# Who is responsible for triggering Application Not Responding Dialog in Android?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

Who is responsible for triggering Application Not Responding Dialog in Android, in case the input events are not handled within the 5 sec?
Is it

> Dalvik Runtime Env

or

> any specific manager in android Framework

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be useful:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

Comment: Thanks Nerd. I have got answer.